# the Play framework 2 crashes on validation error

Tags: validation, playframework-2.0, classnotfoundexception, jvm-crash

Play framework 2.2.0 crashes when user enters a value out of range in a field that is binded to a model field with @Min annotation.

To ensure that it's not a problem caused by my own models, I modified computer-database sample from play directory. I added an Integer value (testVal) to the Computer.java model and added an inputText to editForm.scala.html and added Ebean auto-DDL generation comment to the first line of 1.sql.

Now when I edit a Computer and enter a value less than minimum value for testVal field, play crashes and this error is displayed:

```
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:mem:play
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[ERROR] [02/09/2014 08:54:52.050] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]       [ActorSystem(play)] Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/PropertyNotFoundException
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:227)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:187)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:115)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate(ValidationContext.java:370)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolation(ValidationContext.java:284)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolations(ValidationContext.java:246)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:289)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:478)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:199)
at play.data.Form.bind(Form.java:327)
at play.data.Form.bindFromRequest(Form.java:215)
at controllers.Application.update(Application.java:67)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(routes_routing.scala:113)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(routes_routing.scala:113)
at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$7$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:183)
at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:377)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:56)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90)
at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:278)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:274)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29)
at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 38 more

[error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default- dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/PropertyNotFoundException
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:227) ~[hibernate-validator.jar:5.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:187) ~[hibernate-validator.jar:5.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:115) ~[hibernate-validator.jar:5.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate(ValidationContext.java:370) ~[hibernate-validator.jar:5.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolation(ValidationContext.java:284) ~[hibernate-validator.jar:5.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolations(ValidationContext.java:246) ~[hibernate-validator.jar:5.0.1.Final]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[play]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/PropertyNotFoundException
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:227)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:187)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:115)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate(ValidationContext.java:370)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolation(ValidationContext.java:284)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolations(ValidationContext.java:246)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:289)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:478)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:199)
at play.data.Form.bind(Form.java:327)
at play.data.Form.bindFromRequest(Form.java:215)
at controllers.Application.update(Application.java:67)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(routes_routing.scala:113)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(routes_routing.scala:113)
at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$7$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:183)
at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:377)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:56)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90)
at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:278)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:274)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29)
at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 38 more
```

Is it possible that the installed play framework is corrupted?

Comment: The reason may be the hibernate-validator version. Check your version of hibernate-validator whether it is compatible with play fm 2.2.0. If you are using 5.x of validation here is the migration guide: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateValidatorMigrationGuide

Comment: I solved it by using play.db.validation.constraints.Min isntead of javax.validation.constraints.Min. I will check this out. Thanks.